# Unable to complete a Custom Filter Pipe in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am building a Product List project in Angular 2 & want to use a custom pipe to 'filter'. I have researched in many sites including here, then I found that pipes are now declared in app.Module declarations & not inside the component. But still unable to display my application & wondering what causing my project to not to work.

product-filter.pipe.ts

```js
    import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/Core';
    import { IProduct } from './product';

    @Pipe({
    name: 'productFilter'

    })

    export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: IProduct[], args: string[]): IProduct[] {
        let filter: string = args[0] ? args[0].toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filter ? value.filter((product: IProduct)  =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) :    value; 
    }
    }
```

I have filtered product list in template using pipe character

product-list.component.html

```
     <div class='col-md-2'>Filter by:</div>
                <div class='col-md-4'>
                    <input type='text' 
                     [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <h3>Filtered by: {{listFilter}} </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='table responsive'>
                <table class='table' *ngIf='products && products.length'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <button class='btn btn-primary'
                                    (click)='toggleImage()'>
                                    {{showImage ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Image 
                                </button>
                            </th>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Available</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>5 Star Rating</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor= 'let product of products |  productFilter:listFilter'> 
                            <td>
```

My app.module file with declaration of pipe.

app.module.ts file

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.Component';

    import { ProductFilterPipe } from './products/product-filter.pipe';

    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent,ProductListComponent,ProductFilterPipe],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

I would be thankful if someone can help me out with this as I am trying to find if I have missed something.

Comment: Please post code instead of images. Also check browser console for any errors.

Comment: make sure your pipe is exported on the module containing your pipe and import that module on the module where you want to use the pipe.

Comment: @sanket code is posted.

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: @Mehari you mean to say that i have to export it even from app.module file? i'm using the pipe in my HTML to filter the products & is there any other module that i have to create to use it apart from html?

Comment: yes... error loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/Core as "@angular/Core" from http://localhost:3000/app/products/product-filter.pipe.js

Comment: Try changing @angular/Core to @angular/core in `product-filter.pipe.ts` By mistake you have used C in upper case.

Comment: @M.Ammar post the error stack trace too.

Comment: oops thanks mate @Sanket for noticing that..it worked... i do checked coding's earlier since typescript is extremely type sensitive but I've missed this....

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: IProduct[], filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filterBy ? value.filter((product: IProduct) =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) : value;
    }
}
```

instead of

```
export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {    
    transform(value: IProduct[], args: string[]): IProduct[] {
        let filter: string = args[0] ? args[0].toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
        return filter ? value.filter((product: IProduct)  =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) :    value; 
    }
}
```